# Why should I use "ought to"?

Tags: word-choice, formality, modal-verbs, contemporary-english, obligation

Is "ought to" still used in modern English? If yes, in what contexts is it used, and is it used more in formal or informal cases?

Comment: While the usage of *ought to* has been declining steadily in the last 300 years, it is still [incredibly common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+to%2Cought%2Cought+not%2Ctable&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5). (The linked Ngram shows that it is roughly 1/3 as frequent as the word *table* today, and *table* is not at all an obscure word.) The question is when should you use it, and when to use *should* or *must*.

Comment: @Peter Shor - Sorry, I do not understand why  you aren't satisfied by Ms Peters consideration: "it is otherwise replaced by modals such as should and must in non-fiction writing of all kinds, everywhere in the world."

Comment: Basically, if a word is used 1/3 as often as *table*, it is an incredibly common word. In my experience, it is still very common in positive statements, although it is not used as anywhere near as much in the negative.

Comment: @Carlo_R I suspect you many have misunderstood what Ms Peters is saying.  For a start, she specifically mentions non-fiction writing; implying that her assertion doesn't apply to fiction, or to spoken English.  Also, the sentence that you quoted also says "ought still works affirmatively as a marginal modal".  Yes, it's still used.  It's still very common.  I use it regularly (probably every day), both in spoken and written English.  Peter's Ngram just confirms that I am not an exceptional case in this regard.

Comment: @Mehper: I bet you had no idea this question was going to open such a can of worms! I think it's one of those pathological cases (in the mathematical sense of [one whose properties are considered atypically bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_(mathematics))), in that the word is (relatively) common, so competent speakers tend to have pretty clear ideas of acceptable usage *in their own idiolect*. But there's considerable variation relating to chronological period, geography, spoken/written register, etc. (as you oughta have realised by now! :)

Comment: @JSBձոգչ: Not that I really have a position here, but might you be able to explain to me (in [chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage)) why you don't think "usage" is a valid tag for this Q?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm glad to open this can of worms :) The answers and comments are really helpful.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar: As I implied, I particularly like this question because it's one where all native speakers can have a view (we're all perfectly familiar with the word *ought*, and we all know our own usage). So it really highlights the difference between *recommended* and *[widely] accepted* usages. Potentially confusing for non-native speakers looking to find how *they* should use the word, but sometimes that's just the nature of natural language.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Is "ought to" still used in modern English?

Yes, it is.  Quite a bit, in fact.

> If yes, in what contexts is it used, and is it used more in formal or informal cases?

That’s an interesting question, because it turns out that *ought* can sometimes be quite formal, but it can sometimes be quite informal. It just depends how it’s used.  Here are two examples from opposite ends of that register spectrum:

- Ought we be placing our filthy feet on the davenport, young man? **[VERY FORMAL, REPRIMANDING]**
- Ya think that’s somethin’, do ya?  Ya oughta see my ol’ lady!  **[VERY INFORMAL]**

The simple answer to your question is that *ought* gets used all the time, in all registers and speakers.  It’s a perfectly normal word for expressing **either** obligation **or** probability.  It is one of the lighter in strength of several nuanced alternatives in this list:

- You ought to call home.
- You should call home.
- You have to call home.
- You need to call home.
- You must call home.

Whether the first or the second of those is the stronger in obligation depends on the speaker, but I have ordered them according to my own somewhat nebulous perception of increasing strength.

Like its close cousin *should*, modal *ought* also has a second sense having nothing to do with obligation, but only of possibility / probability / likelihood:

- I ought to have enough by then.
- I should have enough by then.
- I may have enough by then.
- I might have enough by then.

Those four are all about likelihood or probability, not obligation. The speaker believes it varyingly possible, or even probable, that they will have enough by then.

“Ought to” is so commonly used that you’ll sometimes see it written as “outta”, “oughta”, or “oughtta” by writers attempting to write in dialect, such as *“Hey Mack, ya really outta getcherself a new broad!”*

*Ought* works mostly like a modal auxiliary, no more admitting words like *do*, *had*, or *will* to the verb phrase than one involving *should* would. That’s because, per the OED, **“as an auxiliary of predication it has become indefinite as to time.”** These are therefore all ungrammatical in standard English:

- *I’ll not ought to go by then.
- *We won’t ought to go.
- *We hadn’t ought to’ve gone.
- *We didn’t ought to go.

Although some of those do occur in some speakers, they are considered highly non-standard, and would convey a very strong rustic or unlettered tone to any character in whose mouth you put such words. Indeed, the OED even goes so far as to label *“did ought”* as ***dialectic, colloquial,*** and ***vulgar***, which is about as harsh a condemnation as it ever makes.  Here’s one of its citations for this sort of “vulgarity” <sup><sub>(in the classical sense :)</sub></sup>:

- 1942 M. Innes *Daffodil Affair* i. 17 ― And I hope that none here will say I did anything I didn’t ought. For I only done my duty.

Obviously that speaker has other markers of education or station, such as the non-standard “I done”, reinforcing the picture we are to have of them.

In contrast, speakers who naturally use double modals (like “might should”) will do the same with *ought*, forming such constructs as *might ought to*. Since these are not ungrammatical in those speakers, constructions such as this one become possible: *“You might ought to do something about that tire.”*  In contrast to the previous example, this one sounds merely folksy to my hear, not ungrammatical.

In my own particular flavor of English, whenever *ought* is used in the negative, the *to* particle in front of the following infinitive is **always** suppressed, making it in form just like the modal *shouldn’t*:

- You oughtn’t be so picky.
- You ought not enunciate so clearly: you’re spitting.
- You ought never put your unhatched chickens to the count.

In the same way, for me the *to* is also suppressed when used in question inversion, although question inversion with *ought* sounds rather formal, perhaps even stuffy:

- Ought we go now?

I can’t imagine it gets used much in first-person singular, perhaps because there are plenty of alternatives that come more readily to the tongue:

- Ought I call you a cab?
- Should I call you a cab?
- Shall I call you a cab?
- May I call you a cab?

In this regard of suppressing a following *to* under negation or inversion, modal *ought* behaves like modal *need*, which is also somewhat more formal-sounding:

- You needn’t go so far as that. [NEGATION]
- Need we really be so formal? [INVERSION]

From a purely syntactic viewpoint, you can swap in *ought* for *need* in both examples above without changing anything else.  Regarding *to*-suppression, the [Wiktionary entry for *ought*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ought?rdfrom=Ought#Usage_notes) has this in its usage notes:

> Ought is an auxiliary verb; it takes a following verb as its complement. This verb may appear either as a full infinitive (such as “to go”) or a bare infinitive (such as simple “go”), depending on region and speaker; the same range of meanings is possible in either case. Additionally, it’s possible for ought not to take any complement, in which case a verb complement is implied, as in, “You really ought to [do so].”

I do not know the geographic distribution of the *to*-suppression portions of Anglophonia, but it has been suggested that there are British speakers who require the *to* and American speakers who forbid it.  If so, it may be that this is another one of those many forms of speech prevalent during colonization that wound up better preserved abroad than in Britain itself.  Certainly there are plenty of citations of *to*-suppression in English literature from the 16<sup>th</sup> through the 19<sup>th</sup> centuries; here are a few from the OED:

- 1589 *Pasquil’s Ret.* B, ― Her Maiestie layeth such a logge vppon their consciences, as they ought not beare.
- 1601 Shaks. *Jul. C.* I. i. 3 ― You ought not walke Vpon a labouring day, without the signe Of your Profession.
- 1648 Milton *Tenure Kings* (1650) 14 ― On the autority of Law the autority of a Prince depends and to the Laws ought submitt.
- 1815 *Zeluca* III. 318 ― Do not get habituated to a word you ought never use.
- 1868 Browning *Agamemnon* 796 ― How ought I address thee, how ought I revere thee?

To my ear, the Milton and the Browning sound archaic, having *to*-suppression in the positive, but those in the negative sound normal (as least insofar as the *ought* use is concerned).  I don’t know why suppressing the *to* particle sounds slightly archaic when in the positive, but not at all so in the negative or under inversion, but it does.

The only completely obsolete use of *ought* that I am aware of is using it as the simple past tense of *to owe*.  This is a non-modal use and so is subject to inflexions.  The OED lists examples of *oughteth*, *oughted*, *oughting*, and says that  all such use is either *obsolete* or *dialectic*, allowing for an apparently non-obsolete Scots use such as:

- 1822 Scott *Nigel* v, ― We aught him the siller, and will pay him wi’ our convenience.

Or is that now also obsolete even in Scotland? I don’t know whether there are any Scots who might still say such a thing; perhaps so.  But the rest of us would say *“We owed him”* there.

Comment: Sam Gamgee, *The Lord of the Rings*: "You didn't ought to have done that!" (Quoted from memory.)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/615016/2085).

Answer (score 17):

It is always interesting to read what individual native speakers of different English dialects think of this or that word or construction. However, even an educated native speaker with some background in linguistics can share his or her opinion that does not necessarily coincide with observable general trends/rules. To answer a question like this, one needs to do some research.

Incidentally, the Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English is the bible for anyone who is seriously interested in descriptive English grammar. Obviously, it takes a bit longer to produce such a work than googling.

Now about the marginal modal "ought to". Unsurprisingly, it is pretty rare (breaking news!). It is not among the nine most frequent modal verbs (will, would, can, could, may, should, must, might, and shall). The verb "ought to" is (generally) so rare compared with other modal verbs that the authors of LGSWE decided to exclude it from most figures and even discussion in their grammar. That's why Geoffrey Leech said that

> "One should not waste hours of valuable classroom time teaching *shall* and *ought to*!" (Leech 2003: 236)

or

> "Already in Present-day English we seem to be reaching a stage where some modals (*shall*, *ought to*, *need*) are reaching the end of their useful life" (Leech 2003: 236).

Here are two illustrative tables from Leech 2003:

**Written English**

[image: Leech2003 ought written]

**Spoken English**

[image]

There is nothing surprising in these tables (i.e. that "ought" has been on the decline). Linguists have known this for at least fifty years. **The general consensus among linguists is that "ought" is falling out of use** (Cappelle and Desutter 2010, Collins 2009, Myhill 1997, among many, many others). In fact, I don't know of any linguist who would argue the opposite.

Martin Harris (in Harris 1986) shares a funny story about how his two teenage sons, "speakers of educated standard British English", "informed" him that *ought* is "*an old word*", used by people like him, meaning *should* (p. 347). That was in England in the 1980s.

In any natural language, there is a lot of variation. Some native speakers use "should" instead of "ought" in questions and negative sentences, some say things like "did we ought to leave so soon". Some native speakers say "oughtn't to open"; some, esp. in the US, say "oughtn't open", and some prefer "didn't ought to open". Some people think that "ought" should be used in cases when your judgment is based on external rules, like social conventions or institutions, as opposed to "should" used for the moral judgment stemming from the speaker's/writer's own personal criteria (Bouscaren et al. 1992). Some don't.

DeCapua 2008 argues that "use and choice of modals also **vary** somewhat **regionally across the United States**. **In some areas, for instance, *ought to* occurs more frequently than in others** [emphasis mine - Alex B.]" (p. 233).

However, we can observe general, *supra-dialectal* trends:

- *ought is more common in speech than in writing* - 56% (spoken), 44% (written) in Cappelle and Desutter 2010. Collins 2009 reports the speech-writing ratios 3:1 for BrE and 4:1 for AmE;
- *should is much more common that ought*, the ratio is 9:1;
- *deontic ought is much more common that epistemic ought*;
- *ought is more common in declarative sentences (in spoken English)* etc.

The authors of the MW Dictionary of English Usage, "the finest work of scholarship on English grammar and usage I have ever seen" (Geoffrey Pullum), mention that oughtn't is regionally limited in the US, "being found most commonly in Midland and Southern areas of the Atlantic Seaboard and in parts of the Northern Midland area." They also argue, based on thorough research, that oughtn't has "somewhat limited use in writing, mostly in reported speech or light prose."

Incidentally, Pam Peter's Guide is well-written and based on current linguistic research. David Crystal calls it "a reliable style guide."

Now, this is what Pam Peters actually wrote in the Cambridge Guide:

> **So while *ought* still works affirmatively as a marginal modal expressing obligation** [emphasis mine - Alex B.], **it’s** otherwise **replaced** by modals such as *should* and *must* **in nonfiction writing** of all kinds, everywhere in the world.

See, for example, [this video](https://aeon.co/videos/ought-we-accept-hume-s-severing-of-any-connection-between-is-and-ought) (BBC Radio 4 and The Open University), where the speaker uses should and ought interchangeably.

Comment: What about 'oughta'? That's very common, maybe more than 'may'.

Comment: @Mitch, Yes, my intuition tells me that "oughtta" is rather common but I don't see how we could check this. COCA has 34 occurrences of "oughtta" and 1 of "ougtha", nothing for "otta". BASE doesn't help us much, either.

Comment: The difficulty with these corpuses is that they record -written- usually standard speech very well, but not spoken/informal/common but non-standard speech.

Comment: The *MW Dictionary of English Usage* has some very good info on *ought* [right here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA701&lpg=PA701&dq=%22ought+not%22+-%22ought+not+to%22&source=bl&ots=nZtSkdA6U6&sig=_V1c0t5vivvqCLJ-O21dfBA1uLw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mzwRUPG4JMa5rQG1moCgCA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22ought%20not%22%20-%22ought%20not%20to%22&f=false), which while you have doubtless yourself read, most others have not. As for its regional analysis, I’m from the [Inland North](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_Northern_American_English), and find *oughtn’t* wholly unremarkable.

Comment: @tchrist, I was glad to see that you didn't say something like "you oughta have read this" :)

Comment: @tchrist, Joking aside, I like your answer, esp. the part "ya really outta getcherself a new broad!" However, I would have to disagree with you when you say that "ought gets used all the time, in all registers and speakers." A bit too sweeping, don't you think?

Comment: Despite your scholarship, Alex, the problem remains that your ultimate paragraph is stating an untruth: there is no shortage of examples of *ought* being used in nonfiction everywhere, exactly the contrary of what is stated. I cannot approve of misleading people this way.

Comment: I don't believe that Pam Peters meant that *ought* is dying out of the language. She meant that it was being used as a semi-modal verb (i.e., marginal modal) rather than a modal, and that its use was becoming restricted to obligation (distinguishing it semantically from *must* and *should*).

Comment: @tchrist, I'm willing to question Peter's claim - show me some evidence, e.g. how "ought" and "should" have been used in different registers and dialects. Your or my or someone else's intuition doesn't count. Corpus findings are preferred.

Comment: It’s easy to find instances of *ought* in technical writing. Surely you have manuals you can search electronically. I suppose I could tally up how often *ought* occurs in the PubMed corpus, or pull out sentence examples from there. It isn’t a question of whether it prescriptively “should” occur there; it’s one of whether it descriptively “does”, of which I cannot believe you have any doubt. Existence proofs are trivial; for example, “The true "rootdn" of the target server ought not be used; an arbitrary...” to name just one.

Comment: @tchrist, trivial? Not so sure. I searched the text of "Programming Perl: Unmatched power for text processing and scripting" (2012), and here's what I got: "ought" 16 occurrences, "should" 179 occurrences, "must" 184 occurrences etc. See what I mean? It's not really about non-occurrence of "ought"; it's about the rarity of "ought", compared to other modal verbs.

Comment: @AlexB. Odd, I get 17 occurrences. But in any event, your last paragraph seems to say that *ought* either does not occur, or else should not occur, in non-fiction writing.  I believe neither of those; what about you?

Comment: @tchrist, idk, that's what Amazon says. My favorite passage: "And what are these 'easy jobs' that *ought* to be easy? [...] It *should* be easy to run external programs .... It *should*  be easy to send those same tidbits .... It *should* be easy to develop .... And, of course, it *should* be easy to compile .... (p. xxiii).

Comment: @tchrist, the way I understand that paragraph from Peter's Cambridge Guide (not mine) is that 'ought' is being replaced/outnumbered by 'should' in those contexts. I don't know Dr. Peters myself but I don't think she'd ever say that something should not occur somewhere in English.

Comment: The longer this debate continues, the more puzzled I become.  Three things seem evident: (1) in general, _should_ is more common than _ought_; (2) the usage of _ought_ has been in a slow but steady decline; (3) neither of the first two points mean that _ought_ is "rare," "odd," "improper," "extinct," "obsolete," or "abnormal" – it's still a word one will read or hear on occasion.  There are now over five dozen comments here, and most all of them seem to support those three non-contradictory statements in one way or another. Just my opinion, but perhaps the debate ought to come to a close.

Comment: @J.R., I agree with (1), (2), and in part with (3). What hasn't been addressed here - and this is something I'm going to investigate in my research (not here)- is how common/rare "ought" is in the speech of British teenagers. COLT 1000 most frequent words: shouldn't (55), may (101), must (199), need (283), should (381) etc. "Ought" is not on that list. Just saying. And yes, let's agree to disagree and finish this discussion.

Comment: @AlexB.: I'm not surprised "ought" is not on that list; I expected it to be in the same category as [other "rare" words](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought%2Chammer%2Ctooth%2Cyellow%2Cwaves%2Ctelevision%2Cplants&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5), such as _hammer, tooth, yellow, waves, plants_, and _television_.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have mostly finished off your questions about contexts where *ought to* is used, and whether it's used more in formal or informal cases.  Peter Shor, Alex B, and tchrist mention the regional form *didn't ought to*.  Tchrist also mentions *hadn't ought* and *might ought to*, and notes that the OED says *did ought* is *dialectic, colloquial*, and *vulgar*.

*Should ought to* is another form sometimes seen (ref. [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should+ought&year_start=1880&year_end=1980&corpus=0&smoothing=0)).  In transcriptions it's often rendered as *should oughta* or more tersely.  Here's a [*should ought to of* example](http://books.google.com/books?id=4M0B-Hi1co4C&pg=PT100&lpg=PT100&dq=%22nessary%22&source=bl&ots=_XLn56ton7&sig=a-PRcE72NoZvLWNIotT_AfL3bXU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D6cWUIvrBYO7rQHhiIGoDQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22nessary%22&f=false), ca. 1914-1919, from ***[You Know Me Al](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Know_Me_Al)***, by Ring Lardner.  It represents colloquial or untutored midwestern US letter-writing of the time, perhaps exaggerated:

> I shut them out to-day and they should ought not to of had four hits but should ought to of had only 2 but Bodie don't cover no ground and 2 fly balls that he should ought to of eat up fell safe.

On page 354 of ***[Modality in Contemporary English](http://books.google.com/books?id=4M0B-Hi1co4C&pg=PT100&lpg=PT100&dq=%22nessary%22&source=bl&ots=_XLn56ton7&sig=a-PRcE72NoZvLWNIotT_AfL3bXU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D6cWUIvrBYO7rQHhiIGoDQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22nessary%22&f=false)***, S. J. Nagle comments on linguistics issues raised by *should ought to*, *might should ought to*, *might should better*, etc., apparently discussing whether these fall within some double- or multiple-modals system or instead are anarchic.

Comment: I get get 'colloquial'. But 'dialectic'? And 'vulgar'? Really?

Comment: @Mitch, Near the middle of his answer, tchrist shows a cite the OED terms *vulgar*, and suggests it's meant in the [classical sense](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vulgar#Adjective), ie, "Having to do with ordinary, common people".  Also, *[dialectal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dialectal)*, "Of or relating to a dialect" or "Not linguistically standard" undoubtedly would be a better word choice than *[dialectic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dialectic)* with its "Any formal system of reasoning..." and "A contradiction of ideas..." senses.

Answer (score 0):

Pam Peters writes in *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (2004):

> *Ought* seems to have reached the end of an evolutionary phase in which it might have become a fully fledged modal. But the trappings of its older identity as a lexical verb have hung around — in the fact that *to* is almost always there to link it with the following verb, and in the use of *do* support in negative statements. So while *ought* still works affirmatively as a marginal modal expressing obligation, it is otherwise replaced by modals such as *should* and *must* in non-fiction writing of all kinds, everywhere in the world.

Comment: Neither should nor must imply anything about the current condition.

Comment: I perhaps am mistaken, but I've never read a sentence in which *ought to* is introduced by *do* in the negative (for example, *"you **don't** ought to go the party uninvited"*). I wonder if such statement is correct, or else if I have misunderstood what Ms Peters is claiming in your quotation.

Comment: @Evan Carroll. Could you expand your comment? I don't speak English, so I have some difficults to understanding that.

Comment: @Carlo_R. if you use the term "ought to" you're making an implicit statement about the present condition. You'd never say the sun "ought to" come up at 8 AM: firstly, the sun can't react to instruction, secondly the sun already rises at 8 AM. *Ought to* implies the condition is mutable and it's not currently that way. Your replacements *should* and *must* don't carry that burden.

Comment: @Paola, a little piece: "You oughtn't to work so late" have to be replaced with "You didn't ought to work so late" said Ms Peters.

Comment: In the U.S., you can't say "You didn't ought to work so late" unless you're south of the Mason-Dixon line. You should say "You ought not to work so late" or "You oughtn't to work so late" or "You oughtn't work so late".

Comment: @PeterShor When you use “ought not” / “oughtn’t”, you don’t ever use the “to”, in my experience. It becomes a real modal.

Comment: @Carlo_R. This is wrong: Usage of *ought* has nothing to do with whether something is fiction or nonfiction.  It is a perfectly normal word, used in all situations.

Comment: @tchrist: you don't need to use the "to" (like you do in the positive), but lots of people do. Consider [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not%2Cought+not+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3).

Comment: @PeterShor It actually sounds wrong to me to use the “to” in the negative the way you do in the positive.  I can’t generate it and would boggle a moment on hearing it.

Comment: We talking talking here, or writing? _Oughta_ ['ɔɾə] is mostly speech, like _gonna, wanna, hafta,_ and all the other proto-auxiliaries. There really aren't any good conventions for its use in written English; or, rather, there are too many opinions and too little agreement.

Comment: @Paola - The Longman Grammar notes that contemporary speakers often bypass the problem by putting ought into a subordinate clause: "I don't think you ought to work so late."

Comment: @Carlo_R: I think the Longman Grammar is wrong. Consider [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+you+ought+not%2C+don%27t+think+you+ought&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: See also [this discussion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) of modals and their paraphrases.

Comment: @tchrist - strange, most examples of ought were found in British fictional discourse.

Comment: @Peter Shor - I do not know what corpus data is used for the Longman Grammar, probably it is not the same used in ngram.

Comment: @Paola That’s because *ought* is like a modal, so you can’t use things like *do, did, will, won’t* etc on it.  You can’t say “do should”, “do ought”, “will should”, “will ought”.

Comment: @tchrist - That construction (You didn't ought to work so late) may well go back to the roots of 'ought' in the lexical verb 'owe', said Ms Peters.

Comment: Gah! Is this a verbatim quote? If so, format it as a quote, give a link and then at least give an additional intelligent comment about its relevance. Otherwise, this is at most worthy of being a comment.

Comment: **Owe**? I don't know whether it is at the root of the verb form *ought*, but the *owe* I'm familiar with means something close to *being indebted to someone*. Does Ms Peters intend a different meaning? And what exactly is a *lexical verb*?

Comment: @tchrist. That's precisely what I thought and the reason why I said I have never encountered such a usage of *ought to*.

Comment: Ms Peters said (verbatim quote): "ought - This word is a lone wolf in English grammar - an estranged relative of the verb *owe*.", @Paola

Comment: Sorry if that came across as rude. How about this: Verbatim (or close) quotes should be formatted as such (using '>'). Also please give a link to your reference. And an answer that is only a quote is only worth a comment unless you can add some relevant commentary to point out how it applies to the question.

Comment: @Mitch I also hadn’t at first realized that Carlo had copied the entire section from the cited book, without adding anything of his own. I have reformatted his answer so that this is now clear. I still think it’s in very bad form to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Paola: [google/wiki tells me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_verb) that a 'lexical verb' is what you usually think of as a run-of-the-mill verb, only to distinguish it from helper/auxiliary/function verbs like 'is' 'or 'have' that indicate tense. I guess Peters might consider modal verbs (from a small finite class) are more like function verbs than lexical verbs. Yes, 'lexical verb' sounds funny because one tends to think "aren't all verbs, or words for that matter, lexical?".

Comment: @Paola. However, I know; the Swan (the book that you use) do not say the same things that Ms Peters said (see Swan - third edition - page 403 and 404); but even the Swan does not agree with tchrist because this book report this example "It oughtn't to rain today". Hence, it is absolutely false that "to" is suppressed in negative construction.

Comment: @Carlo_R. No, your book is absolutely wrong, that’s all.  I swear by my authority as a native speaker that in my dialect, your cited example is absolutely ungrammatical.  You cannot contradict me in this. At most, you may be able to find another native speaker who does not find it ungrammatical, but I absolutely do so, and therefore I cannot be wrong in this statement regarding my own dialect.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Actually, you really **can** say the sun ought to be coming up around 8am tomorrow morning, in the sense that you believe this to be likely because you are not quite sure of the exact moment of sunrise, given that that moment changes daily. *Ought* can also be about probability, not just about obligation.

Comment: That's an argument I'm willing to accept; however, I have a decent understanding of the term *morning* and astronomy, and so at least for most populated climates, there is no probability that the sun will not come up short of a solar catastrophe of an unforeseen magnitude.

Comment: @tchrist. In a sense, this is the "problem" with English: it is used so widely, and by native speakers living so far apart, that it becomes difficult to create sentences which are universally considered to be grammatical. I don't doubt for one second that in your *dialect*, as you put it, *ought not* is followed by a bare infinitive, but this is not the case in British English, for example. So I suppose that we should all be a bit more tolerant.

Comment: This doesn't say that "to" always follow "ought", just mostly. She never says that "don't ought to..." is correct.

Comment: @PeterShor: I'm not arguing with you (I ought not to do that), but I thought [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+you+ought+not%2Cdon+%27+t+think+you+ought%2C+do+not+think+you+ought&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) was an interesting complement to yours.

Comment: @Carlo: Pam Peters is an Australian; tchrist and I are Americans. I expect "didn't ought to" is used in Australia, and I suppose that it's possible that it is used in the American South, where they use a number of double modals (e.g. "might could") which aren't used by the rest of the U.S. Between tchrist and me, we can personally attest that it's not used in California, the Midwest, New Jersey, New York, and New England.

Comment: And Googling, it does look like "didn't ought to" is indeed used in the U.S. South and in England. I expect it occurs in Australia as well.

Comment: @PeterShor Hm, I wonder what “didn’t ought to” means then. Past tense, so somehow a previous obligation condition?  BTW, I don’t see “did/had” + modal as a double modal, since *did* and *had* aren’t modals, just verbal particles conveying tense/time.  Plus “did should” sounds a great deal less grammatical than “might should” sounds.

Comment: @tchrist: You're right, it's not a double modal. My mistake. And when [Georgette Heyer](http://books.google.com/books?ei=7ZsQUKC2JOTm0QH_uoFA&id=eUAgAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22didn+%27+t+ought+to%22+Houston&q=%22didn+%27+t+ought+to%22#search_anchor) used it, it meant "ought not to have", and it seems she put it into the mouth of someone who wasn't speaking the poshest dialect.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: _"My book is not a generic book. You cannot contradict what Ms Peters said._" Perhaps so, but you ought not to quote one paragraph from Ms Peters and consider that to be the end of the discussion. Ms Peters accurately documents the [shift in usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ought+not%2Cshould+not&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5) away from _ought not_, but that doesn't mean the expression is entirely extinct. As a matter of fact, Google books returns over 3 million hits for _ought not to_; many seem a bit archaic, but not all do.

Comment: As a follow-on to my previous comment, [here is an example](http://books.google.com/books?id=AD0i-VtU9GEC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22ought+not+to%22&source=bl&ots=vu2xcg-WGE&sig=_P_iFuot9j8gV4tHAYBUqY4uMrA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N5oQUNiGK6XSiALRoYCwDA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAzgy#v=onepage&q=%22ought%20not%20to%22&f=false) where _ought not to_ is used in a modern context. This was found on Page 6 of 3,440,000 results in a Google book search.  As common as _should_? Absolutely not. But in no way is @tchrist wrong in his assertion that _ought_ "is a perfectly normal word" – nothing abnormal about it.

Comment: @J.R. Remember that when you’re searching specifically for instances of “ought not to”, you’re necessarily discarding all hits from those of us who suppress *to* following *ought not*, *oughtn’t*, *ought never*, etc. For the record, my last published book contains 17 instances of *ought*, exactly 17 of which were positive not negative. The negative somehow sounds more formal; I wonder whether that has anything to do with the *to*-suppression.

Comment: @tchrist: I realize there are plenty of other ways to structure my search; but I needn't be that exhaustive to make my point :^)

Comment: I know Pam Peters is a professor of linguistics, but as @Peter Shor points out, she's also an Australian who edits Australian dictionaries. I'm suspicious that what she writes here may be more biased opinion/her own personal style guide, rather than the result of extensive global surveys that I doubt Cambridge University Press paid to have conducted. In short, I trust her not.

Comment: @J.R. You’ve (indirectly) made me realize that there is a difference with where you put the *never*.  If it goes before *ought*, there is no suppression of *to*, but if it follows it, there is. “You never ought to run in church,” versus “You ought never run in church.”  Curious, eh?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, obviously you didn't even bother to read the preface in Pam Peter's guide. Otherwise, you wouldn't have said that.

Comment: @Alex B.: I don't have access to the text - I've only seen the fragment cited by Carlo. I voiced a suspicion, is all. But the issue here is largely about what is and what isn't *used by competent speakers* (not *prevalent*), and what's *acceptable* (not *sanctioned by a particular style guide*). Whether Peters is bona fide or not is rather beside the point. Like tchrist, and Humpty Dumpty, and unlike Carlo, I'm usually content with my own version of "acceptable English usage".

Comment: I'm afraid there's some misunderstanding. Pam Peter's Guide is *descriptive*. She doesn't tell you how to speak or write. She merely reports research findings of other linguists. Acceptability is when this or that native speaker says, "sounds/looks good to me!" Linguists observe and/or ask native speakers (the more the better) and write rules.

Comment: @Alex: The problem is that for "ought", Peter's "descriptive" guide does not in any way describe the actual usage in the U.S. I believe that here she extrapolated the grammar of Australia to that of the U.K. and the U.S. I suspect that she's usually fairly careful about doing that, but she slipped up in this instance.

Comment: @J.R. Your Ngram convinces me that Longman knows what they're talking about here (as they almost always do).

Comment: @PeterShor, so, I assume that 1. You've read the relevant entry in the Cambridge Guide yourself; 2. You've done a number of elicitation and acceptability judgment experiments yourself with US and British native speakers; 3. You've searched several corpora besides Google Ngrams and tried to analyze your findings.

Comment: @Alex B.: You've made the point that CGEU is descriptive. Clearly several here don't think it accurately describes *their* usage (and by implication, the usage of others within their linguistic community). The issue here is mainly concerned with the possibility that Carlo_R is interpreting CGEU as *prescriptive*. CGEU could be 100% accurate in everything it says about usage (and trends), but with a word as common as *"ought"*, I don't think many native speakers would change the way they use it just because they discovered they were in the minority in global terms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I see. I can't tell you why Carlo thought that the Cambridge Guide was prescriptive. However, I *do* know that some  L2 English learners think of English grammar as "cut and dried, right and wrong". On the contrary, English grammar is "imbued with points of variability to explore" (Pam Peters).

Comment: @Alex B.: Carlo isn't a native speaker, but he's dilligently and enthusiastically attempting to improve his command and understanding of English. Naturally, at his level there would be a tendency to treat *everything* in a publication like CGEU as "prescriptive". For his purposes, at his current level, practically everything listed as "most common current usage" *any* such tome is effectively the same thing as "recommended usage". But I expect by now he has realised that competent speakers don't always feel they ought better "follow the crowd" (Can I get away with that? **I** think I can! :).

Comment: @AlexB. That can be said for almost any language, not just English. The problem is that they tend to simplify the grammar, when they teach you a foreign language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, a funny quote for you from the How to be British Collection (2003). "Expressions to learn: 'E nicked it off a lorry and now the coppers 'ave done 'im for it. *Avoid saying*: That's not correct English, Mrs. Jones - it says so in my grammar book."

Answer (score -4):

Use *ought to* when you wish to emphasize that:

- things aren't that way now.
- and, you wish things to be that way.

I think *ought to* is slightly more formal but only in the very nature that it adds emphasis without invoking vulgarity, and that's usually formal.

Here is an example,

> *I know the users of english.stackexchange.com don't have the final say so on the decision to unban users, but they **ought to** have the final say so.*

Comment: Do you know what "Schleichwerbung" in German means? I don't know if "surreptitious advertising" is the correct translation. However, that is not part of an answer and -imho- does not belong to here.

Comment: It's additional information. What's wrong with that, where is that against the rules?

Comment: "without invoking vulgarity..."  What do you mean?

Comment: (I for one don't have strong feelings this way or the other, because as far as the elections are concerned, that note might actually attract a couple more people who weren't even aware of them, and as far as your own candicacy goes, you'll be shooting yourself in the foot at best, which is your fair right, but as far as the rules go,) that bit was unrelated to the question at hand and too localized, i.e. obsolete in a couple weeks.

Comment: Well, the new look&feel is much better, though ... Whatever